# My script doesnt seem to be executed on GPU, although Tensorflow-gpu is installed

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a machine with cuda 10.1 and tensorflow and tensorflow gpu 1.14.0 installed. I am running a python script that trains a CNN in a virtualenv. I am indicating in the source code that I want to use the GPU, as follows:

```
import os
os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"]="PCI_BUS_ID";
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]="0";
```

However, when I run the script, the training epochs are taking a lot to finish. Here is the output of my nvidia-smi:

[image]

**What I think is strange is why the GPU utilization is that low and why my python script is not appearing in the processes list. Here are the outputs of some commands I have tried:**

```
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(log_device_placement=True))
```

the output is

> 2019-10-14 09:53:12.674719: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:142] Your CPU supports
>   instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
>   FMA 2019-10-14 09:53:12.679047: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42]
>   Successfully opened dynamic library libcuda.so.1 2019-10-14
>   09:53:12.784993: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful
>   NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be
>   at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero 2019-10-14
>   09:53:12.785744: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA
>   service 0x55f155c59650 executing computations on platform CUDA.
>   Devices: 2019-10-14 09:53:12.785771: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor
>   device (0): GeForce RTX 2080 Ti, Compute Capability 7.5 2019-10-14
>   09:53:12.806453: I
>   tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency:
>   3600000000 Hz 2019-10-14 09:53:12.807345: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service
>   0x55f15605dfc0 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
>   2019-10-14 09:53:12.807408: I
>   tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:175]   StreamExecutor
>   device (0): ,  2019-10-14 09:53:12.807829: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful
>   NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be
>   at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero 2019-10-14
>   09:53:12.808859: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0
>   with properties:  name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti major: 7 minor: 5
>   memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.545 pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 2019-10-14
>   09:53:12.809148: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   09:53:12.809313: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcublas.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   09:53:12.809481: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcufft.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   09:53:12.809531: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcurand.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   09:53:12.809572: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcusolver.so.10.0'; dlerror:
>   libcusolver.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   09:53:12.809611: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcusparse.so.10.0'; dlerror:
>   libcusparse.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   09:53:12.811997: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42]
>   Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7 2019-10-14
>   09:53:12.812038: W
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1663] Cannot dlopen
>   some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices... 2019-10-14
>   09:53:12.812059: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device
>   interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix: 2019-10-14
>   09:53:12.812067: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 
>   2019-10-14 09:53:12.812072: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N  Device
>   mapping: /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_GPU:0 -> device:
>   XLA_GPU device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0 ->
>   device: XLA_CPU device 2019-10-14 09:53:12.812372: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/direct_session.cc:296] Device mapping:
>   /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_GPU:0 -> device: XLA_GPU
>   device /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:XLA_CPU:0 -> device:
>   XLA_CPU device

Other command I tried is

```
>>> with tf.Session() as sess:
    devices = sess.list_devices()
```

The output is

> 2019-10-14 09:55:52.398317: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful
>   NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be
>   at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero 2019-10-14
>   09:55:52.399249: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0
>   with properties:  name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti major: 7 minor: 5
>   memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.545 pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 2019-10-14
>   09:55:52.399355: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   09:55:52.399399: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcublas.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   09:55:52.399437: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcufft.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   09:55:52.399475: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcurand.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   09:55:52.399509: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcusolver.so.10.0'; dlerror:
>   libcusolver.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   09:55:52.399544: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcusparse.so.10.0'; dlerror:
>   libcusparse.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   09:55:52.399552: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42]
>   Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7 2019-10-14
>   09:55:52.399557: W
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1663] Cannot dlopen
>   some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices... 2019-10-14
>   09:55:52.402143: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device
>   interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix: 2019-10-14
>   09:55:52.402162: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]

Finally, I also tried this

```
>>> from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
>>> print(device_lib.list_local_devices())
```

With the following output

> 2019-10-14 10:00:52.389511: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_gpu_executor.cc:1005] successful
>   NUMA node read from SysFS had negative value (-1), but there must be
>   at least one NUMA node, so returning NUMA node zero 2019-10-14
>   10:00:52.390582: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1640] Found device 0
>   with properties:  name: GeForce RTX 2080 Ti major: 7 minor: 5
>   memoryClockRate(GHz): 1.545 pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 2019-10-14
>   10:00:52.390741: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   10:00:52.390811: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcublas.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcublas.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   10:00:52.390854: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcufft.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcufft.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   10:00:52.390897: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcurand.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcurand.so.10.0:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;
>   LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   10:00:52.390934: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcusolver.so.10.0'; dlerror:
>   libcusolver.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   10:00:52.390968: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Could
>   not dlopen library 'libcusparse.so.10.0'; dlerror:
>   libcusparse.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or
>   directory; LD_LIBRARY_PATH:
>   /usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64: 2019-10-14
>   10:00:52.390975: I
>   tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:42]
>   Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.7 2019-10-14
>   10:00:52.390980: W
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1663] Cannot dlopen
>   some GPU libraries. Skipping registering GPU devices... 2019-10-14
>   10:00:52.390990: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1181] Device
>   interconnect StreamExecutor with strength 1 edge matrix: 2019-10-14
>   10:00:52.390994: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1187]      0 
>   2019-10-14 10:00:52.390998: I
>   tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1200] 0:   N  [name:
>   "/device:CPU:0" device_type: "CPU" memory_limit: 268435456 locality {
>   } incarnation: 17281747132467712783 , name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
>   device_type: "XLA_GPU" memory_limit: 17179869184 locality { }
>   incarnation: 3885020928213180904 physical_device_desc: "device:
>   XLA_GPU device" , name: "/device:XLA_CPU:0" device_type: "XLA_CPU"
>   memory_limit: 17179869184 locality { } incarnation:
>   15667518323180153095 physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_CPU device" ]

Interestingly, when I run these commands, the python process appears in the NVIDIA-SMI monitor.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

From your log:

> Could not dlopen library 'libcudart.so.10.0'; dlerror: libcudart.so.10.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory;

You installed CUDA 10.1 but TF-GPU requires CUDA 10.0, so you need to install it (no need to uninstall the 10.1 one, they can coexist)

Comment: Let me try that. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Recently I sent to friends instructions to install cuda and tf-gpu using conda (because this is the fast) - after some while of searching in the internet, my protocol is this:

```
##########################
# Install Miniconda
##########################

mkdir -p ~/install
cd ~/install
wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh
# I guess on a mac you should do
# wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-MacOSX-x86_64.sh
bash Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh

#########################
# install nvidia driver
# so these are the linux (ubuntu) commands
# for mac, maybe one should follow the scheme
# removing nvidia drivers first
# and then download newest nvidia driver
# and install it
# and reboot
#
# If you are using a laptop without gpu, just skip this block
#########################

sudo apt purge nvidia-*   # remove all nvidia driver first

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-418

sudo apt install nvidia-cuda-toolkit

# reboot
sudo reboot

#########################
# install machine learning stuff keras tensorflow-gpu
#
# if you are installing in a laptop without gpu,
# replace 'tensorflow-gpu' by 'tensorflow'!
#########################

conda create --name keras
conda activate keras
conda install python ipython jupyter pandas scipy seaborn scikit-learn tensorflow-gpu keras pytest openpyxl graphviz


#########################
# finally, test a successful installation by:
# entering:
ipython # and there trying:

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices())

# should list gpu
# sth like:

physical_device_desc: "device: 0, name: GeForce GTX 1050 Ti, pci bus id: 0000:01:00.0, compute capability: 6.1"
, name: "/device:XLA_GPU:0"
device_type: "XLA_GPU"
memory_limit: 17179869184
locality {
}
incarnation: 14085000268159177816
physical_device_desc: "device: XLA_GPU device"
]
```